# Passing value from 2 jQuery range slider to PHP

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

I want to use range slider for query in mysql/php to obtain a list.
But I don't understand how to pass a variable from jQuery to a php file.
I read [this page](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/pass-values-of-sliders) and others, but still don't get the result.
This is the code for jQuery that I want to pass, what should I do to pass the variable?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#slider-range1" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                values: [ 75, 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                }
            });
            $( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range1" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                " - $" + $( "#slider-range1" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-range2" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                values: [ 75, 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                }
            });
            $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                " - $" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $.ajax("file.php", {variable1:/*variable value*/, variable2:/*variable value*/, variable3:/*variable value*/, variable4:/*variable value*/}, /* insert ajax result*/);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>
        <label for="amount1">Price range:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount1" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
    </p>
    <div id="slider-range1"></div>
    <p>
        <label for="amount2">Price range:</label>
        <input type="text" id="amount2" style="border: 0; color: #f6931f; font-weight: bold;" />
    </p>
    <div id="slider-range2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to submit the value everytime it change you can try my code, but you have a bad idea if you do that.. its better you have a button to tell your server that the client is done picking the price.

i just update you code i hope it help.

```
    <script>
        $(function() {
            var sliderChangeCallback = function(){
               var amount1 = $( "#amount1" ).val(), amount2 = $( "#amount2" ).val()

               $.ajax({
                   url : "your url",
                   data : {
                       "amount1" : amount1,
                       "amount2" : amount1
                   },
                   error : function(){
                       "call back error"
                   }
               })
            };

            $( "#slider-range1" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                values: [ 75, 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                    sliderChangeCallback();
                }
            });
            $( "#amount1" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range1" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                " - $" + $( "#slider-range1" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

            $( "#slider-range2" ).slider({
                range: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 500,
                values: [ 75, 300 ],
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                    sliderChangeCallback();
                }
            });
            $( "#amount2" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
                " - $" + $( "#slider-range2" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

        });
    </script>
```